# Getting same object orientation with different rotation methods in python

Tags: python, transforms, transform-orientation

I can rotate an object by assigning rotation_euler values or using the bpy.ops.transform.rotate() operator.

I wrote this code:

```
import bpy

E1 = bpy.data.objects["E1"]
E2 = bpy.data.objects["E2"]
bpy.data.objects["E1"].rotation_euler = (0, 0, 0)
bpy.data.objects["E1"].rotation_euler = (1, 0.5, 1.5)

E1.rotation_mode = 'ZXY'
E2.rotation_mode = 'ZXY'

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = E2
E2.select_set(True)

#bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].type = '...'

bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5, orient_axis='Z')
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1, orient_axis='X')
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=0.5, orient_axis='Y')
```

which results in differently oriented objects, no matter which transform_orientation mode I select ('GLOBAL', 'LOCAL', ...).

How can I calculate the values to be used in the operator calls to make E2 coincident with E1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you only need to set the constraint axes correctly. The last three lines were modified.

```py
import bpy

E1 = bpy.data.objects["E1"]
E2 = bpy.data.objects["E2"]
bpy.data.objects["E1"].rotation_euler = (0, 0, 0)
bpy.data.objects["E1"].rotation_euler = (1, 0.5, 1.5)

E1.rotation_mode = 'ZXY'
E2.rotation_mode = 'ZXY'

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = E2
E2.select_set(True)

#bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].type = '...'

bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5, constraint_axis=(False, False, True))
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1, constraint_axis=(True, False, False))
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=0.5, constraint_axis=(False, True, False))
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is perfectly valid, but an alternative (and generally better practice for scripting in Blender) is to modify the actual data of the object, rather than trying to recreate the operation you want with `bpy.ops`. This will bypass any issues that will crop up with context etc, and will generally lead to more predictable results.

```py
import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import Euler, Vector, Matrix
import numpy as np


obj = C.object
mesh = obj.data
mw = obj.matrix_world

# get a blank matrix with your rotation applied to it
# Matrix.Rotation takes -> 
    # angle of rotation in radians, 
    # size of the matrix (4x4) in this case,
    # axis to rotate
rotation_matrix = Matrix.Rotation(np.radians(90), 4, 'X')

# then just multiply objects world matrix by the rotated matrix using @ notation
rotated = mw @ rotation_matrix

# then set the object's world matrix to this new matrix
obj.matrix_world = rotated

# doing it in the objects local space is much the same, except with matrix_local
loc_mat = obj.matrix_local
new_rotation_matrix = Matrix.Rotation(np.radians(90), 4, 'Z')
rotated_local = loc_mat @ new_rotation_matrix

obj.matrix_local = rotated_local
```

When it comes to scripting, it only really matters what gets the job done, but as a rule, modifying the transform matrix vs using `bpy.ops.transform`, altering a mesh directly through `bmesh` vs. hacking something together with `bpy.ops.mesh`, will generally be a better practice to aim for.

Relevant topic in the [bpy docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#using-operators)

Comment: I would generally agree, nonetheless I think that relying on consolidated routines, such as the most used Blender standard operators, can be worth it, especially if they perfectly meet your needs.